# How do I make Java Object from this JSON with GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

JSON:

```
{"station":[{"id":"p2","websiteId":"p2","name":,"label":"Price","latitude":,"longitude":,"zip":"","region":"South"}],"parameters":{"ozone":{"value":"0.044","unit":" ppm","color":"17,250,11","colorHex":"11fa11","arrow":"unchange_gray"},"pm25":{"value":"NA","unit":"","color":"000000","colorHex":"000000","arrow":""},"temperature":40.4,"wind_speed":4.5,"wind_dir":"SE"},"seasonalParameter":"ozone","forecast":[],"version":"1.5"}
```

My attempt at the objects:

```
public class AirObjects {


    @SerializedName("station")
    public List<Station> stationData;



    public class Station {

        @SerializedName("id")
        public String id;

        @SerializedName("parameters")
        public Parameters parameters;
    }

    protected class Ozone
    {
        @SerializedName("value")
        public String ozone_value;

        @SerializedName("unit")
        public String ozone_unit;

        @SerializedName("colorHex")
        public String ozone_color;

        @SerializedName("arrow")
        public String arrow;


    }

    protected class Parameters
    {
        @SerializedName("ozone")
        public Ozone ozone;

        @SerializedName("temperature")
        public String temperature;

        @SerializedName("wind_speed")
        public String windSpeed;

        @SerializedName("wind_dir")
        public String windDirection;
    }

    protected class Sites
    {
        @SerializedName("id")
        public String id;

        @SerializedName("websiteId")
        public String websiteId;

        @SerializedName("name")
        public String name;

        @SerializedName("label")
        public String label;

        @SerializedName("latitude")
        public String latitude;

        @SerializedName("longitude")
        public String longitude;

        @SerializedName("zip")
        public String zip;

        @SerializedName("region")
        public String region;


    }

}
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Well, I get the id just fine, but for the other stuff I get null.

Comment: To start with, you are missing lots of fields.  If you want to define a POJO which maps to that JSON you need to go through it field by field and make sure you have them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the structure of your json (you can use http://jsonviewer.stack.hu to see the structure of a json value):

[image: json structure of ops question]

Now you should define the POJO for this structure.

1. You have `station` array, `parameters` object, `seasonalParameter`
   String, `version` String and `forecast` array at first level of your
   json. So you should define a POJO which has those fields.
2. `station` is an array which has one object and that object has `id`,
   `websiteId`, `name`, etc fields. So you should define a POJO for
   station which has those fields.
3. `parameters` is an object which has `ozone`, `pm25`, `temperature`,
   `wind_speed` and `wind_dir` fields. So you should define a POJO for which has those fields.
4. `ozone` and `pm25` has same fields, so they should be same class's
   instances. You should define a POJO for them.

Now lets see our POJOS:
1) Your first level POJO:

```
public class Holder {
    private Station[] station;
    private Parameters parameters;
    private String seasonalParameter;
    private String version;
    private Object[] forecast;
}
```

2) Station POJO:

```
public class Station {
    private String id;
    private String websiteId;
    private String name;
    private String label;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
    private String zip;
    private String region; 
}
```

3) POJO for parameters field:

```
public class Parameters {
    private Param ozone;
    private Param pm25;
    private double temperature;
    private double wind_speed;
    private String wind_dir;
}
```

4) POJO for both ozone and pm25 fields:

```
public class Param {
    private String value;
    private String unit;
    private String color;
    private String colorHex;
    private String arrow;
}
```

**Test:**

```
String json = "{\"station\":[{\"id\":\"p2\",\"websiteId\":\"p2\",\"name\":\"\",\"label\":\"Price\",\"latitude\":\"\",\"longitude\":\"\",\"zip\":\"\",\"region\":\"South\"}],\"parameters\":{\"ozone\":{\"value\":\"0.044\",\"unit\":\" ppm\",\"color\":\"17,250,11\",\"colorHex\":\"11fa11\",\"arrow\":\"unchange_gray\"},\"pm25\":{\"value\":\"NA\",\"unit\":\"\",\"color\":\"000000\",\"colorHex\":\"000000\",\"arrow\":\"\"},\"temperature\":40.4,\"wind_speed\":4.5,\"wind_dir\":\"SE\"},\"seasonalParameter\":\"ozone\",\"forecast\":[],\"version\":\"1.5\"}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Holder item = gson.fromJson(json, Holder.class);
```

**Note:** Json sample you shared is not a valid json. "name": ,"latitude": ,"longitude": , are changed to "name": "","latitude": "","longitude": "" to make your json valid.